# Mybatis - org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found)

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

I have created a new project using mybatis to connect to a postgresql database. when I call the save method I get the following error:

> org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): com.mysite.hrmanager.repository.mapper.MstBizExpMapper.selectAll
> at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod$SqlCommand.(MapperMethod.java:235) ~[mybatis-3.5.9.jar!/:3.5.9]
> at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.(MapperMethod.java:53) ~[mybatis-3.5.9.jar!/:3.5.9]
> at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.lambda$cachedInvoker$0(MapperProxy.java:108) ~[mybatis-3.5.9.jar!/:3.5.9]
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1705) ~[na:na]
> at org.apache.ibatis.util.MapUtil.computeIfAbsent(MapUtil.java:35) ~[mybatis-3.5.9.jar!/:3.5.9]
> at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.cachedInvoker(MapperProxy.java:95) ~[mybatis-3.5.9.jar!/:3.5.9]
> at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:86) ~[mybatis-3.5.9.jar!/:3.5.9]
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy82.selectAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
> at com.mysite.hrmanager.service.MstBizExpService.selectAll(MstBizExpService.java:23) ~[classes!/:na]
> at com.mysite.hrmanager.controller.DemoController.fetchExpsDetailList(DemoController.java:32) ~[classes!/:na]

The mapper xml file is as follows (in com/mysite/hrmanager/repository/mapper)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.mysite.hrmanager.repository.mapper.MstBizExpMapper">
    <resultMap id="mstBizExpMapper" type="com.mysite.hrmanager.entity.MstBizExpEntity">
        <result column="engineer_id" jdbcType="numeric" property="engineerId" />
        <result column="biz_exp_id" jdbcType="numeric" property="bizExpId" />
        <result column="start_at" jdbcType="varchar" property="startAt" />
        <result column="end_at" jdbcType="char" property="endAt" />
        <result column="rd_flg" jdbcType="char" property="rdFlg" />
        <result column="bd_flg" jdbcType="char" property="bdFlg" />
        <result column="dd_flg" jdbcType="char" property="ddFlg" />
        <result column="cd_flg" jdbcType="char" property="cdFlg" />
        <result column="ut_flg" jdbcType="char" property="utFlg" />
        <result column="it_flg" jdbcType="char" property="itFlg" />
        <result column="pt_flg" jdbcType="char" property="ptFlg" />
        <result column="om_flg" jdbcType="char" property="omFlg" />
        <result column="summary" jdbcType="varchar" property="summary" />
    </resultMap>

    <select id="selectAll" resultMap="mstBizExpMapper">
        select * from engineer_id
    </select>
</mapper>
```

The mapper interface is as follows:

```
package com.mysite.hrmanager.repository.mapper;

import java.util.List;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper;
import com.mysite.hrmanager.entity.MstBizExpEntity;

@Mapper
public interface MstBizExpMapper {

    List<MstBizExpEntity> selectAll();
}
```

And the service class is as follows:

```
package com.mysite.hrmanager.service;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.mysite.hrmanager.entity.MstBizExpEntity;
import com.mysite.hrmanager.repository.mapper.MstBizExpMapper;

@Service
public class MstBizExpService {
    @Autowired
    private MstBizExpMapper mstBizExpMapper;

    public List<MstBizExpEntity> selectAll() {
        return mstBizExpMapper.selectAll();
    }
}
```

-------------------added-------------------
The applicatin.properties is as follows:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://hr-manager_db:5432/dev
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

spring.messages.basename=messages
spring.messages.cache-duration=-1
spring.messages.encoding=UTF-8
```

And the build.gradle is as follows:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.12.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.mysite'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:2.2.2'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

// tasks.named('test') {
//  useJUnitPlatform()
// }
```

Comment: Due to some configuration issue, MyBatis cannot find the mapper. You need to add the relevant configurations to the question. Or, start from a working example like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues) and make small change at a time. This way, you would know the exact cause of a failure.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I added two files to the question (application.properties and build.gradle).

Comment: Now I can see you are using mybatis-spring-boot-starter :) It usually is automatic, but sometimes extra configuration is needed. Read the [doc](https://mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/). If you cannot figure out, consider using the spring-boot template in this [repo](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues).